# What is a 'field' in Bash?

Tags: bash

```
field

    A unit of text that is the result of one of the shell expansions. After expansion,
    when executing a command, the resulting fields are used as the command name and 
    arguments.
```

What does this mean? If i do `ls /etc/*` will i get a bunch of fields (filenames) eg: motd, passwd - in which case what about files with space? This is globbing and you get a bunch of words where the whitespace is preserved.

Guys on #bash on freenode mentioned:

```
<geirha> The term field is mainly only used when talking about the read command
<geirha> read -r foo bar <<< "$line"    splits line on IFS and assigns the first field (word) to foo, and the rest of the line to bar
<geirha> # line='Hello, World!'; read -r foo bar <<< "$line"; echo "\$foo is $foo. \$bar is $bar"
<shbot> geirha: $foo is Hello,. $bar is World!
<[arx]> # touch foo 'bar baz' $'qux\nquux'; printf '<%s>' *; echo
<shbot> [arx]: <bar baz><foo><qux
<shbot> [arx]: quux>
<[arx]> veek: globbing generates WORDs, the whitespace is preserved.
```

But it's not very clear to me... `<<<word` is like a *HERE* so word is expanded based on IFS and what you get are fields?? But then in the other example by [arx].. what's that about?

Comment: The first definition is more general than the second. And the first is rarely used (at least, I never hear anyone referring to the arguments of a command as "fields" generally). So the arguments to `ls /etc/*` are expanded first by the shell to their literal names and then `ls` takes over. In the `read` case, the inputs are split per the `IFS` and the individual results of splitting are called "fields".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call "a bunch of words where the whitespace is preserved" is basically the definition of a field. Think of a field as a boundary of information, separated by the IFS-variable (word splitting).

It is perhaps easier to visualize this using awk, since awk has a clear field usage.

Consider this:

```
echo foo + bar + haz | awk '{print $3}'
```

awk splits using IFS as well, and here we're asking to print field $3. If we divide the echoed string into separate units, we get these:

```
value  field #
foo    $1
+      $2
bar    $3
+      $4
haz    $5
```

The line will therefore print "bar".

Now, suppose we tell awk to split using "+" as a separator instead of IFS:

```
echo foo + bar + haz | awk -F+ '{print $3}'
```

The fields will then look like this:

```
value  field #
foo    $1
bar    $2
haz    $3
```

The output will therefore be "haz".

Perhaps you can think of fields as columns of data to get a better grasp of it. For more in-depth reading regarding word splitting fields in bash, I'd suggest taking a look at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting